# How do I get rid of "Note1", "Note2", ... for footnotes placed in the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes

I am writing an article based on the APS (American Physical Society), Physical Review B article format.  This places all footnotes in the numbered bibliography at the end of the article.  All citations and footnotes get superscript markers.  I'm using:

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,superscriptaddress,twocolumn,showpacs,
                                             longbibliography]{revtex4-1}
. . . 
\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
. . .
\bibliography{BibTeX_Bibliography}
```

among other packages.

I am using TeXstudio and I made the bibliography with JabRef.  Each footnote is properly placed in the bibliography section at the end of the article, but each one gets a "Note1", "Note2", etc. in front of the footnote text.  I can't figure out how to get rid of this.  When the .bbl file is created, I get things like:

```
\bibitem[{Note1()}]{Note1}
Note1, \bibinfo{note}{\protect {Bonsall  . . . spherical geometry. See Ref.\protect
  \tmspace +\thickmuskip {.2777em}\protect \onlinecite {name1}, Appx. D.}}

\bibitem[{Note2()}]{Note2}
Note2, \bibinfo{note}{\protect {Eq.~\protect \ref {eq:Ecor, a_c} is . . . indices,
\protect \cite {Bonsall1977} and  . . . ``exact''}}.
```

I deleted some of the text for brevity.  `\tmspace +\thickmuskip {.2777em}` was added by the computer, not by me.  The result is:
[image]
Reference #7 is a regular bibliography entry, which is correct.  In the footnotes I had to use `\protect` around all of the text, i.e. `\footnote{\protect{...}}` because otherwise the first character in the text is automatically set to lower case.  I also put `\protect` in front of the equation and reference citations or I get error messages.  These work fine, but I can't get rid of the "Note1, "...  I could go into the .bbl file and manually delete these, but then when I recompile the file, the .bbl gets overwritten and I get the same thing again.  I also noticed that for entry #9, if I end with `"exact."`, then the system thinks I don't end with a period so it will insert one automatically and I end up with `"exact.".`

I tried using the `notes2bib` and `endnotes` packages, but these don't help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't get rid of footnotes in the bibliography, because that's the style of Physical Reviews.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: egreg, Inquisitor is asking about the text "Note1" that is being added to the footnotes as they appear in the bibliography.

Answer (score 2):

The apsrev bibliography style should be used with the correct version number: In this case `\bibliographystyle{apsrev}` should be replaced by `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}`. I guess the version number should be the same as the one used in the document class (`\documentclass[...]{revtex4-1}`).

Just for completeness: The REVTEX 4.2 Author’s Guide mentions that the `\bibliographystyle{...}` macro should be used in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`)<strike>,  which differs from standard LaTeX</strike>.

Comment: I don't remember if Lamport is specific on this, but when I taught LaTeX classes, I always said that the `\bibliographystyle` command should go in the preamble, and I would consider this to be “standard LaTeX.” LaTeX won't enforce this (for backwards compatibility reasons) and in practice it won't make a difference where the command appears, but in general, you want to have all declarations of style in the preamble and not scattered about the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the preamble.

```
\usepackage[convert-footnotes]{notes2bib}%comments and endnotes in the %bibliography

\bibnotesetup{
note-name = ,
use-sort-key = false
}
```

Worked for me, but I am not using APS style. I have:

`\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`

Answer (score 1):

One can use `footinbib` or `nofootinbib` as an optional argument in the document class. In revtex4.2 the former is default (see [authors guide](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/auguide/auguide4-2.pdf) VII). For instance the full document class could read as:

```
\documentclass[english,10pt,aps,prb,twocolumn,nofootinbib,amsmath,amssymb,groupedaddress]{revtex4-2}
```

For PRB footnotes are allowed on the page they appear (See [PRB page](https://journals.aps.org/prb/authors)). For most other APS journals the footnotes need to appear in the bibliography.

Answer (score -1):

Try getting rid of `\bibliographystyle{apsrev}` (I think the `prb` specification in your document class should automatically call the correct bibliography style file).

Comment: ..."[you] think"? Can you please confirm whether this is valid?

Comment: Removing \bibliographystyle{apsrev} doesn't work.

Comment: Note that *changing* the bibliography style did work for me.  That is, keep the command `\bibliographystyle{<name>}` but replace what's in `<name>`.  I don't know how to solve this problem if it's necessary for you to use `apsrev`.